# concatenate sql

Tags: sql

Write a query to concatenate staff id with first 3 characters from the staff name. Display with an alias as official_mail and order the results in ascending order.

my code:

```
select staff_id as official_mail
from Staff
order by official_mail;
```

how to write first 3 characters?

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT()`, `SUBSTR()`, `SUBSTRING()`.

Comment: Column staff_id's data type?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL/MSSQL

```
SELECT CONCAT(staff_id,SUBSTRING(staff_name,1,3)) AS official_mail
FROM Staff
ORDER BY official_mail;
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9c13b/1

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.